# ul menu dropped after image inserted in another div

Tags: html, css

I've got a strange problem in app I am creating. There are one big div with `display:table` with one div `display:table-row`. In the row there are 2blocks, aside and content which are `display:table-cell`. In aside there is ul menu for whole app, in content there is currently shown content. Problem is, when i add image into content, whole menu in aside is pushed down by height of the immage. But image is in different block, it shouldn't be able to move with aside.

I made fiddle with problem, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CxREh/2/). As you can see, there's menu on left side in aside block, and image on the right. I put there at bottom of css file image with width 200px, you can change it to see the problem. With small values it do nothing, but with width around 50px it start to change the menu.

How to remove this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top`; to aside

```
aside {
    background-color: #31383E;
    color: #989B9E;
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```